# Where are lists of all files recently opened by a process?

Tags: windows, handle

If I remeber correctly somewhere windows has an utility to show all opened files by processes and all recently modified file (without having to make a normal hard disk search)

Maybe in the administrative tool?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're talking about several completely separate lists.

**Currently opened** files can be listed by [ProcExp](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653), [handle](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655), [OpenedFilesView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/opened_files_view.html) and several other tools which show **open handles** held by processes.

**Recently modified** files can be found in the *Security* log in Event Viewer (`eventvwr.msc`). However, you will only see those files which you manually enable **auditing** on them (under *Properties → Security → Advanced*), since it's disabled by default.

On NTFS, system programs can access the **[change journal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USN_Journal)** (aka USN journal; see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363798%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)), which logs all volume changes including file modifications. The only userspace tool that I know of which can display the entries is [`fsutil`](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/fsutil_usn.mspx?mfr=true).

Comment: `Task MAnager->Performance->Resource monitor->disk` too

Comment: Or that. (I'm stuck with Win XP here.)

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in way to see open handles, but you can see a list of in-use files and folders and what process has them open with [Unlocker](http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/) (as well as close, copy, delete, etc. them).

You can see a list of file and folder access with [Windows Security Auditing](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771395%28WS.10%29.aspx) <sup>[[XP]](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310399)[[7]](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/advanced-security-auditing-in-windows-7-and-windows-server-2008-r2.aspx)</sup>, which *is* included with Windows 2000 and up.